# What is difference between URLWithString and fileURLWithPath of NSURL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, path, nsstring, nsurl

In my code I have to use `URLWithString` to play streaming(`HLS`) video and `fileURLWithPath` to play local video.

What is the difference between these two methods?
How should I use single method to play both videos.

Also I need to show last frame as still image when `HSL` video ends. Its now showing blank screen when it ends. How should i achieve this?

Comment: "Also I need to show last frame as still image when HSL video ends" Unrelated to the first part of your question. Ask it as a different question! Two for the price of one.

Answer (score 21):

`+URLWithString:` produces an `NSURL` that represents the string as given. So the string might be `@"http://www.google.com"` and the URL represents `http://www.google.com`.

`+fileURLWithPath:` takes a path, not a URL, and produces an `NSURL` that represents the path using a `file://` URL. So if you give it `/foo/bar/baz` the URL would represent `file:///foo/bar/baz`.

You can of course construct a file URL string manually and pass it to `+URLWithString:`, but `+fileURLWithPath:` is simpler to use when you already have a path, as you don't have to deal with escaping the string and coercing it to a URL format.

Comment: Just to expand on the last part: a file URL is not merely a path with the word "file" stuck on the front. They work quite differently, and it is unlikely that a human being would deal correctly with the differences. The computer does.

Answer (score 3):

Similar thing happened in my app which use AVAudioPlayer. I tried with `[NSURL URLWithString:path]` and found out it fails to open certain mp3 files. I looked into error by a line like `[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path] fileTypeHint:AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3 error:&error]`, but the error was simply `nil`

However it was resolved by replacing the url with `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]`.

In both case, the path `path    NSString *  @"/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4D96D4AE-2ED4-40B0-85D2-230E1AFA90E7/Documents/01-AudioTrack 01.mp3"  0x1457a8f0` Still I don't know the reason but now I should be careful using `[NSURL URLWithString:]`.

PS. In NSURL Reference document, Apple said as below:

> IMPORTANT
>   To create NSURL objects for file system paths, use fileURLWithPath:isDirectory: instead.

which clearly indicates `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]` should be used for open file, though `[NSURL URLWithString]` also works for some cases.