# Get paths for the Magical Record store files

Tags: ios6, nsfilemanager, magicalrecord

Getting *Cocoa error 260*, which says file not found.

```
NSArray *inputPaths = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[[[NSPersistentStore MR_defaultLocalStoreUrl]absoluteString]stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]error:&folderError];
    if (folderError) {
        [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:folderError.localizedDescription];
    }
```

Why? Or is it any other way to get store files paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer here:

[NSURL path vs absoluteString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176911/nsurl-path-vs-absolutestring)

`absoluteString` is for the remote urls only, for local file urls should be used `path` instead.