# SearchDirectories vs URLsDirectory - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

Why is that when I use URLsForDirectory api of NSFileManager the path differs from that of NSSearchPathForDirectoriesinDomains?

```
let paths = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.CachesDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
let cachePath = paths[0] as! NSURL
print cachePath
```

This gives me an output

```
file:///Users/Labs1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E2BB953D-7CAB-4FB7-BAFA-84C9D962A28E/data/Containers/Data/Application/BB57895F-9D13-46E1-AC48-B76E4FDA2DDF/Library/Caches/
```

With NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains

```
print(NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.CachesDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as? String)
```

I get an output

```
/Users/Labs1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E2BB953D-7CAB-4FB7-BAFA-84C9D962A28E/data/Containers/Data/Application/BB57895F-9D13-46E1-AC48-B76E4FDA2DDF/Library/Caches
```

Is there a way to remove `file:///` in URLsForDirectory?

Comment: just use NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains?

Comment: Please see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16178576/1489885) for details. When you deal with NSURLs you can call the `path` method on it. This strips the scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if let cachesDirectoryPath = NSFileManager().URLForDirectory(.CachesDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true, error: nil)?.path {
    println(cachesDirectoryPath)   // "/var/folders/s_/fxl041zd64l0y6_rjddfbpcc0000gn/T/com.apple.dt.Xcode.pg/containers/com.apple.dt.playground.stub.iOS_Simulator.UIColor-PlayGround-514A4119-E045-4B83-A740-B0C1BBCECBD7/Library/Caches"
}
```