# IOS swift Load Image from gallery by its path

Tags: ios, swift, image, path, local

Good day.I simply created an view which opens gallery picker for a user and user chooses an image.I have to keep track of chosen images and save them for a use till the app uninstalled.The problem is that im using core data to save the necessary info and for me the logical would be to save the image path so later i could get the core data,get all image paths and show them inside image view.The problem is that i receive NSURL from image picker by this code

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!){


    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in
            let path   = editingInfo.valueForKeyPath("UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL") as! NSURL


             self.imageView?.image = UIImage(named:path.absoluteString);
        })

    }
```

and as you can see im trying to apply the image by the path to UIImage.Nothing happens...image view is fully and clearly empty....and i have no clue what i can do to get the image loaded by its gallery path..In android its very easy by gettting bitmap through image path but here its seems impossible?Please help me...Thank you...

One more strange thing...as googlign i found this code to get the pat above but here is the path im getting and why something tell`s me the path should not be like this......

```
assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=5FBCA5A4-06CC-4469-8D0C-B86E7AEE9FCA&ext=PNG
```

Comment: no i dont need that...i have said that i have to save the image for forever use until the app is uninstalled and there is lots of logic which must be done that way so i though to save the path for a better use but seems i cant load image by path

Comment: `let path = ` is misleading as it is a NSURL. you should use `let url = `... and if you need the file path just get `url.path!`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176911/nsurl-path-vs-absolutestring

Comment: btw you should use another UIImage initialiser  initWithContentsOfFile https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/initWithContentsOfFile:

Comment: umm tried did not helped... same result

Comment: both did not work...same nothing show inside image view

Comment: why are you trying to do that after dismissing the vc ? move it before self.dismissViewControllerAnimated

Comment: um ok let me try...but i dont think it will actually change anything

Comment: ummm same result.....let me update my answer i found something

Comment: You need to save your image locally and use that url

Comment: save locally?no other ways?

Comment: I think only the video gets a local file url

Comment: what the.....so i have to save it locally and only after that i would get the normal path???oh my...can you post a code please?

Comment: `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)!.writeToURL(destinationURL, atomically: true)`

Comment: you will need to create a file name generator or save it using the date description + .jpg

Comment: hmmm ok so it comes every image chosen must go localy saved? i knew ios creators pretty slow but...like this...... the ios will blow as the app is high image loading app so i cant do it...ok ill ask my boss see what he will say about this

Comment: try `print(editingInfo[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL])` to see if you get a URL

Comment: yeah i tried million times im getting it

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAsset_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/PHAsset/fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:options: