# Realm must not be nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I updated my app from Realm 0.9x но 2.0.x
Now I have a lot of bug reports from 8, 9 and 10 iOS devices on Crashlytics about fatal exception:

```
Fatal Exception: RLMException
Realm must not be nil
```

Stack trace looks like this:

> RLMObjectStore.mm line 81
>   RLMGetObjects
>
> RLMObject.mm line 154
>   +[RLMObject objectsInRealm:withPredicate:]
>
> RLMObject.mm line 146
>   +[RLMObject objectsInRealm:where:args:]
>
> RLMObject.mm line 140
>   +[RLMObject objectsInRealm:where:]
>
> Sessions.m line 88
>   +[Sessions resultWithSessionsWhere:]
>
> Sessions.m line 128
>   +[Sessions activeSession]
>
> Sessions.m line 102
>   +[Sessions appLaunched]
>
> AppDelegate.m line 60
>   -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]

I can't reproduce bug on debug environment. It touched around 30-40% of users (not at all), and I it looks like only old users are touched.

There is no realm object in this method:

```
/**
 *  Create and returns Realm configuration for sessions database
 */
+(nonnull RLMRealmConfiguration*)realmConfigurationForSessions
{
    RLMRealmConfiguration *config = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
    // Use the default directory, but replace the filename with the 'sessions.realm'
    config.fileURL = [NSURL
                  URLWithString:[[[config.fileURL.absoluteString stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]
                                      stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sessions"]
                                     stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"realm"]];
    return config;
}

+(nullable RLMRealm*)realmForConfiguration:(nullable RLMRealmConfiguration*)config
{
    if (!config) {
        return nil;
    }
    NSError *error;
    // Open the Realm with the configuration
    RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration:config
                                                 error:&error];
    if (error) {
        DLog(@"error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
    return realm;
}
```

Questions: 1) what is the cause of this strange issue? 2) how do I can properly handle error and nil realm value in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That exception [occurs in a pretty straightforward case](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/9484a03f5355fa00df99b3386c9009335d77a6a1/Realm/RLMObjectStore.mm#L57). An error occurred and it resulted in an `RLMRealm` instance not being created when it should have been.

With the information you've provided, it's possible that the way you're constructing your `fileURL` property might not be succeeding in all cases.

My recommendations:

- Use `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]` instead of `[NSURL URLWithString:]`. That one is better optimized for file paths as opposed to web URLs.
- Use `config.fileURL.path` instead of `config.fileURL.absoluteString`. For more information why, [check this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176911/nsurl-path-vs-absolutestring).
- For consistency's sake, use `[NSURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:]` as opposed to `[NSString stringByAppendingPathComponent:]`.

I hope that helped! Let me know if you need additional clarification!

Comment: Ok, it's good. But what about error handling? How can I get a stable working app  if error is occured?

Comment: `[RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration: error:]` will return `nil` if an error occurs, so it's very easy to detect if an error preventing the Realm from being generated has occurred, so you can mitigate it. In this case, (unless some other issue is occurring elsewhere) it'll only occur if the `fileURL` isn't properly formatted and pointing to a valid location on disk. So in this case, verifying your `NSURL` value before passing it to Realm might help. :)