# Can't create temporary directory

Tags: ios, swift3, temporary-files

I’m having trouble createing a temporary directory in iOS using Swift 3.  I’m getting the temporary directory URL from `FileManager.temporaryDirectory`, and trying to create the directory using `FileManager.createDirectory`, but the directory doesn’t appear to exist, and I’m not able to create files in it.  What am I doing wrong?

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let tempDir = fileManager.temporaryDirectory
let tempDirString = String( describing: tempDir )
print( "tempDir: \(tempDir)" )
print( "tempDirString: \(tempDirString)" )
if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: tempDirString ) {
    print( "tempDir exists" )
} else {
    print( "tempDir DOES NOT exist" )
    do {
        try fileManager.createDirectory( at: tempDir, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil )
        print( "tempDir created" )
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: tempDirString ) {
            print( "tempDir exists" )
        } else {
            print( "tempDir STILL DOES NOT exist" )
        }
    } catch {
        print( "tempDir NOT created" )
    }
}
```

This produces the output:

```
tempDir: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D28B9C5E-8289-4C1F-89D7-7E9EE162AC27/tmp/
tempDirString: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/ D28B9C5E-8289-4C1F-89D7-7E9EE162AC27/tmp/
tempDir DOES NOT exist
tempDir created
tempDir STILL DOES NOT exist
```

Comment: You don't have to create the directory, it is already there.

Comment: you should also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176911/nsurl-path-vs-absolutestring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tempDirString` string you are passing to `fileManager.fileExists(atPath: tempDirString )` contains a string, but the string is NOT a file path.  It is a description for human readable purposes, not for machine-readable purposes.  In fact, it is not even a valid URL string (notice the space in it!).

If you want the path, replace this line:

```
let tempDirString = String( describing: tempDir )
```

and instead assign to `tempDirString` the results of the NSURL's `path` function to get the path as a string:

```
let tempDirString = tempDir.path
```

See:  https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurl/1408809-path