# What's the difference between URL.standardized and URL.absoluteURL?

Tags: swift, url

In Swift's `URL` class, there are [`.standardized`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/url/2293170-standardized) and [`.absoluteURL`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/url/1780323-absoluteurl) properties ([`.standardizedURL`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurl/1411073-standardizedurl?language=objc) and [`.absoluteURL`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurl/1414266-absoluteurl?language=objc), and [`.URLByStandardizingPath`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurl/1414302-urlbystandardizingpath?language=objc) in Objective-C's NSURL). There's also [`.standardizedFileURL`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/url/2293229-standardizedfileurl).

I have no idea what the difference is between all these, but there must be one since they provide all of them, right? I mean clearly the `.standardizedFileURL` is meant to only deal with file URLs, but other than that (for instance, if all are called on a file URL), **what's the difference?**

---

From the above-linked docs:

## Swift

> ### standardized
>
> Returns a URL with any instances of “..” or “.” removed from its path.

> ### absolute​URL
>
> Returns the absolute URL.
>
> #### Discussion
>
> If the URL is itself absolute, this will return self.

> ### standardized​File​URL
>
> Standardizes the path of a file URL.
>
> #### Discussion
>
> If the `is​File​URL` is `false`, this method returns `self`.

## Objective-C

> ### standardized​URL
>
> A copy of the URL with any instances of ".." or "." removed from its path. (read-only)
>
> #### Discussion
>
> This property contains a new `NSURL` object, initialized using the receiver’s path with any instances of `".."` or `"."` removed. If the receiver does not conform to RFC 1808, this property contains nil.

> ### absolute​URL
>
> An absolute URL that refers to the same resource as the receiver. (read-only)
>
> #### Discussion
>
> If the URL is already absolute, this property contains a copy of the receiver. Resolution is performed per RFC 1808.

> ### URLBy​Standardizing​Path
>
> A URL that points to the same resource as the original URL using an absolute path. (read-only)
>
> #### Discussion
>
> This property only works on URLs with the file:​ path scheme. For all other URLs, it returns a copy of the original URL.
>
> Like `string​By​Standardizing​Path`, this property can make the following changes in the provided URL:
>
> Expand an initial tilde expression using `string​By​Expanding​Tilde​In​Path`.
>   Reduce empty components and references to the current directory (that is, the sequences “//” and “/./”) to single path separators.
>   In absolute paths only, resolve references to the parent directory (that is, the component “..”) to the real parent directory if possible using `string​By​Resolving​Symlinks​In​Path`, which consults the file system to resolve each potential symbolic link.
>
> In relative paths, because symbolic links can’t be resolved, references to the parent directory are left in place.
>   Remove an initial component of “/private” from the path if the result still indicates an existing file or directory (checked by consulting the file system).
>
> Note that the path contained by this property may still have symbolic link components in it. Note also that this property only works with file paths (not, for example, string representations of URLs).

Comment: Create a bunch of URLs and see what you get. Be sure you create some relative URLs based on other URLs. Be sure to create URLs with various uses of `..` and `.` in the path., etc. This sort of "try it and see" should be done before posting a question like this.

Comment: @rmaddy I've tried that and the tests' output still confuses me: https://gist.github.com/BenLeggiero/b2067317ab253aedeab9c3b0ca4270c1

Comment: Thanks for your gist — that's really comprehensive and useful! These URL properties are very hard to comprehend.

Comment: For future readers, that gist was moved to https://gist.github.com/KyLeggiero/b2067317ab253aedeab9c3b0ca4270c1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `url` is an absolute URL, `url.absoluteURL == url`.

If `url` is a relative URL and has a non-nil `baseURL`, then `url.absoluteURL` returns an absolute URL by resolving the relativity of `url` in the context of `baseURL` (and thus `url.absoluteURL != url`).

If `url` is a relative URL, `url.standardized` does **not** return an absolute URL, and may in fact return a URL that does not resolve the same way as `url` (!) because `url.standardized` removes any leading `..` components of the path.

Example:

```
let base = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com/q/43258046/77567")!
// output: "https://stackoverflow.com/q/43258046/77567"

let rel = URL(string: "../16176911", relativeTo: base)!
// output: "../../16176911 -- ttps://stackoverflow.com/q/43258046/77567"

rel.absoluteURL
// output: "https://stackoverflow.com/q/16176911"

rel.standardized
// output: "16176911 -- ttps://stackoverflow.com/q/43258046/77567"

rel.standardized.absoluteURL
// output: "https://stackoverflow.com/q/43258046/16176911"
```

Comment: Jeez wow... thanks for the in-depth explanation! Will definitely revisit code to make sure it uses the proper one(s) now.

Answer (score 3):

I think the key difference is that two URLs with different absolute paths may actually refer to the same resource, and in that case, they would have the same standardized URL.  Examples of path elements that could cause this are:

```
~ vs /absolute/path/to/user/home/directory
paths that include soft links
/path/to/thing vs /path/to/other/../thing
etc.
```

The standardized url (`URL.standardizedFileURL` in swift) is very useful because two URLs that point to the same file should have the same standardizedFileURL even if they have different absolute paths.  So one should generally use the standardized path if they wish to compare two file URLs.