# Swift convert base 64 string (which is docx file) to (ns data)

Tags: swift, file, base64

I have base64 string which is convertable to docx format file. I checked it in online base64 decoder. In my project I need to convert base64 string to data and sign it using RSA key (which has password and username). In my case I can encode simple string. But when trying to encode base64 string do data , data is nil. So, My question is how can I convert base64 docx fiel to NSData?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your string with

```
let data = Data(base64Encoded: string)
```

You can save the data to a file with

```
FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: path, contents: data, attributes: nil)
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use Data's write method?

Comment: You need to add some operations to make this code work like checking if the file already exists and maybe deleting it. I think it is easier to do everything with the FileManager than to switch between different methods. Also, paths are a bit easier to handle than URLs like in the `data.write` function. You can see this thread for comparison: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176911/nsurl-path-vs-absolutestring

Comment: kkkk You can use `options: .atomic`