# NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject fails to save

Tags: swift, macos, nsarray, nsdictionary, nskeyedarchiver

I have a group of custom objects that I'm converting to `NSMutableDictionary`'s, and then creating an array out of them (this part is currently working as expected).

I'm then attempting to save that array of data as a file using `NSKeyedArchiver`. However, the result of `NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject` always returns `false`.

Below is my logic for saving - am I missing something obvious, or perhaps is this the wrong approach? Thank you!

```
    var groupsArray = [Any?]()

    for group in file!.groups{
        for obj in group.children {
            let objDict = obj.convertToDictionary()

            groupsArray.append(objDict)
        }
    }


    let documents: String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    let filePath: String = URL(fileURLWithPath: documents).appendingPathComponent("file.archive").absoluteString

    let save: Bool = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(groupsArray, toFile: filePath)
```

EDIT: This also fails if trying to save to the `.desktop` or the `.caches` directories.

Comment: If you split out the archiving step and the writing step into two (get the `archivedData(withRootObject:)`, then write it out), where does the error happen? Is the app sandboxed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this method to save

1.Method returns filepath.

```
func filePath(key:String) -> String {
    let manager = FileManager.default
    let url = manager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
    return (url!.appendingPathComponent(key).path)
}
```

2.Code to save to a file using NSKeyedArchiver.

```
NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(groupsArray, toFile: filePath(key: "file.archive"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is `.absoultestring`. If the URL object contains a file URL, then we should use `.path` for working with `FileManager` or `PathUtilities` etc. So here replacing `.absoultestring` with `.path` will solve the issue

for more details about their difference please refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176911/nsurl-path-vs-absolutestring?answertab=active#tab-top)