# AVAssetExportSession add meta data after recording ends

Tags: avassetexportsession

The use case is like this: A video is recorded and saved at a temporary location using AVCaptureFileOutput. After the recording is completed some meta data is to be added to this video and saved with a new filename at a new location.

The recording part is working with the file getting stored at the temporary location. Now I have to rename it, add meta data and save it again to a different location.

1) Can I edit the meta data within the:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error;
```

delagate method?

2) My second approach was to use AVAssetExportSession to do this.

```
AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    exportSession.metadata = NEW ARRAY OF METADATA;

    NSString* outputPath = [[PLFileManager sharedFileManager] pathForAsset:_newAsset];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:outputPath];
    exportSession.outputURL = url;

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:url error:nil];

    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void){
               NSLog(@"Exported to [%@] %@", exportSession.outputURL, exportSession.error);
    }];
```

How ever with this approach I am getting the following error:

Exported to [///var/mobile/Applications/7F9BC121-6F58-436E-8DBE-33D8BC1A4D79/Documents/Temp/final.mov] Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo=0x1555f440 {NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x1555c7a0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12780.)", NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12780)}

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: although I figured out what I was doing wrong, I would still like to hear if there is a more optimised way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out what I was doing wrong. Instead of:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:outputPath];
```

I had to use:

```
NSURL* outputUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputPath];
```

[Expanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16097434/155683)