# NSURLErrorDomain with code=-1100

Tags: swift, ios8, nsdata, nsurl

I was trying to download a picture to my app from

[image]
The request failed with the error NSURLErrorDomain and the code is really -1100. The url should be correct since I checked it in the browser. Anyone knows why?

```
let userImageURL: String! = "http://i.imgur.com/QhCzQoR.jpg";
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: userImageURL);
let request:NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: { (response:NSURLResponse!, imageData:NSData!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData!);
 })
```

Answer (score 29):

The reason you are getting this problem is because you have used

```
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: userImageURL);
```

Instead you should use:

```
let url = NSURL(string: userImageUrl)
```

Comment: This is identical to the previous, upvoted answer from last year.

Comment: There is alot of blurb to go through, this is far clearer.

Answer (score 11):

I code in Objective-C, it should be easy to convert it in Swift (small modification in fact, but the explanation is not that much related to code). 
If you check the error complete message, you'll get:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The requested URL was not
>   found on this server." UserInfo=0x7997b7e0
>   {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file:///http:/i.imgur.com/QhCzQoR.jpg,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=file:///http:/i.imgur.com/QhCzQoR.jpg,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The requested URL was not found on this
>   server., NSUnderlyingError=0x799f3080 "The requested URL was not found
>   on this server."}

Clearly, if you look carefully at the URL, you have `file:///http:/i.imgur.com/QhCzQoR.jpg`, which is not the URL wanted. If you log `url.absoluteString`, you'll see it to your URL, it's you that set it like this.

Why? Because you used `fileURLWithPath:` instead of `URLWithString:`.
So change your line with:

```
let url = NSURL(URLWithString: userImageURL);
```

Some discussions about the differences between theses two:
[What is difference between URLWithString and fileURLWithPath of NSURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097404/what-is-difference-between-urlwithstring-and-fileurlwithpath-of-nsurl)
or the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/fileURLWithPath:).

**Update:** In Swift 4:

```
let url = URL(string: userImageURL)
```

We also recommend from Swift3+ to avoid NSStuff when there is Swift Equivalent: `NSURL` => `URL`.

Comment: I think this method has been changed to `NSURL(string:String?)` in Swift2. Note that when you use this URL to create a request, you'll have to add `!` after `url` variable, because `string` is optional in this method.