# URL(fileURLWithPath: snap.urlImage) Command not working as expected

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm building (study purpose) a solution similar to Snapchat. The idea is to send a picture to another person that can open it. Information is saved to a Firebase-Realtime-Database and, once clicked by the receiver, shows that image.

I'm using Xcode 11.2, Swift4, IOS13, macOS Catalina, SDWebImage (5.2.3)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

details.text = snap.description

let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: snap.urlImage)
print("URL 1 \(url) - end")
print("URL 2 \(snap.urlImage) - end")

imagem.sd_setImage(with: url) { (image, error, cache, url) in
 print("Message 1")
}

}
```

URL saved to Firebase is ok and works fine (I can copy/paste to my browser and download the picture).

Below is the result from the code above:
print("URL 1 (url) - end") result
https:/firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/snapchat-xxxxx.appspot.com/o/images%252FBA5008FB-7D2E-4091-B995-E37879EAB1A2.jpg%3Falt=media&token=72146333-fe8e-4add-be52-1caf037cd1d6 -- file:/// - end

print("URL 2 (snap.urlImage) - end")
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/snapchat-xxxxx.appspot.com/o/images%2FBA5008FB-7D2E-4091-B995-E37879EAB1A2.jpg?alt=media&token=72146333-fe8e-4add-be52-1caf037cd1d6 - end

As you can see, after using URL(fileURLWithPath: snap.urlImage) a " -- file:///" is added to the end of the "url" constant.

If I replace url by snap.urlImage in sd_setImage line it doesn't work (imagem.sd_setImage(with: snap.urlImage)...)

Anyone would have an idea of what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: `fileURLWithPath`, it's a path in the machine (your device which is an iPhone I guess). Like in your Mac : `~/Documents`. What you want is `URL(string: snap.urlImage)` instead. "" -- file:///" is added to the end", but if you do `url.absoluteString` it's at the beginning, that's how `url` are printed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSURLErrorDomain with code=-1100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267352/nsurlerrordomain-with-code-1100)

Comment: Thanks Larme... that worked

Answer (score 0):

```
init(fileURLWithPath path: String)
```

> Initializes a newly created file URL referencing the local file or
>   directory at path

init(fileURLWithPath:) interprets the passed in string as a local file path which I don't think you want. You would use that if for example, you wanted to write that file to your local disk.

What you are actually looking for is the url path to the file on the server.

```
let urlToImage = URL(string: snap.urlImage)
```

keeping in mind that will return an optional so best to protect your code like this

```
if let urlToImage = URL(string: snap.urlImage) {
   imagem.sd_setImage(with: urlToImage)...
} else {
   print("could not find file at that url") //or some other error
}
```

also, I would suggest a different var name for readability... `urlImage` sounds like it's an Image or NSImage, not a path. `imageUrl` would be a better name since it's the url *to* the image.

Comment: Thanks... great info