# Playing Audio From Parse.com

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, avplayer

I am trying to play an audio file i saved on parse.  I am getting the url from the PFFile from the object i saved to parse.  When i run the app the avplayer produces no audio.  I tested to see if the avplayer was playing by the first code snippet below and it prints out "Playing" which means the player is playing but no audio.  I also tried setting the volume for avplayer and that didn't help. Don't understand why it won't play if anyone would like to help me out.

Audio File URL: http://files.parsetfss.com/292b6f11-5fee-4be7-b317-16fd494dfa3d/tfss-ccc3a843-967b-4773-b92e-1cf2e8f3c1c6-testfile.wav

This Code stops avplayer if it is playing:

```
if (player.rate > 0) && (player.error == nil) {
            // player is playing
            println("Playing")
        } else {
            println("Not Playing")
        }
```

AVPlayer Code:

```
let objectAudio: PFObject = object as PFObject
let parseAudio: PFFile = objectAudio.valueForKey("audioFileParse") as PFFile
let audioPath: String = parseAudio.url                       
let urlParse: NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath)!

player = AVPlayer(URL: urlParse)
println(player) //prints out <AVPlayer: 0x79e863c0>
player.volume = 1.0
player.play()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong method to get a NSURL here, you try to create a local file URL from an URL that points to a resource on a remote server.

Instead of `NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath)` you should use the initalizer that accepts an URL string as the input (see here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/initWithString:)

Your current code would point to a local resource which does not exist on the local filesystem whereas it should point to the file on the Parse server.

Just as a reference, the difference between `URLWithString` and `fileURLWithPath` [What is difference between URLWithString and fileURLWithPath of NSURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097404/what-is-difference-between-urlwithstring-and-fileurlwithpath-of-nsurl)

Comment: Thank you so much man fixed my problem by using NSURL(string: url).  Thanks again!