# How do you query video files from parse.com

Tags: ios, uiview, parse-platform

I know how to to retrieve an image file from Parse and store it in an UIImageView but how do you retrieve a video(or movie) file from Parse.com and store it in a UIView to be played (using AVPlayer) ?

Comment: What interface does the player provide for you to supply data? Web url? File url?

Comment: AVPlayer can play remote streams/files

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389961/playing-audio-from-parse-com may help

Comment: Have you tried to extract the video URL from the PFFile and them use it with AVPlayer?

Comment: The player provides File URL to supply data

Comment: I have tried to extract the url from the PFFile using .url

Comment: Hey, you should specify how you want to play the video, where, etc. Maybe some code of what you've tried? I've posted an answer below but more information would be better so that people can help you!

Answer (score 0):

Import the following in your file:

`import Parse
import AVFoundation
import AVKit`

add this before your class definition so that you can access it everywhere as global variables:

`public var audioPlayer = AVPlayer()
public var songNumber = Int()`

add this to your class definition: `AVAudioPlayerDelegate`

Set arrays to store the data:

`var idArray = [String]()
 var nameArray = [String]()`

Your viewDidLoad + getSongs function:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var objectQuery = PFQuery(className: "Songs")
        objectQuery {
            (objectsArray: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            var objectIDs = objectsArray!

             print(objectIDs)

            for i in 0...objectIDs.count-1 {
                    self.iDArray.append(objectIDs[i].valueForKey("objectId") as! String)
                    self.nameArray.append(objectIDs[i].valueForKey("songName") as! String)

                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }

        }
    }

 func getSongs () {
    var songQuery = PFQuery(className: "Songs")
    songQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(idArray[songNumber], block: {
        (object: PFObject?, error : NSError?) -> Void in

        if let audioFile = object?["songFile"] as? PFFile {
            let audioFileUrlString: String = audioFile.url  
            let audioFileUrl = NSURL(string: audioFileUrlString)!
            audioPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: audioFileUrl)
            audioPlayer.play()
        }
    })
}
```

After this code, you can get your `getSongs` function where you want, or if its a TableView then you can set it in a cell with indexPath.row

As the question is a bit broad Im giving a broad answer as I'm not sure how you want to set it and where you want to play it/under what trigger?

Here is a related question I referenced to get you started as well as the docs in Parse.

Even though the question may seem unrelated, the answer and the context is in this question/answer: [Could not cast value of type PFFile to NSURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621340/could-not-cast-value-of-type-pffile-to-nsurl) This link shows you how to query and convert so that you can play a music file.

You should also check out the Parse docs: [File Queries Parse Docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#files)