# Could not cast value of type PFFile to NSURL

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2

I am trying to stream music from parse using Swift 2.0 in Xcode 7 (I have 3 audio files I uploaded in Parse). I have been following a tutorial that came out about 6 months ago but apparently a lot has changed. I have been able to conform to all of the changes except one. When I run the app and tap on a row (which is a song) I get the error:

> Could not cast value of type 'PFFile' (0x10dda2d50) to 'NSURL' (0x10e6d1c10).

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

public var AudioPlayer = AVPlayer()
public var SelectedSongNumber = Int()

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

    var iDArray = [String]()
    var NameArray = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var ObjectIDQuery = PFQuery(className: "Songs")
        ObjectIDQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objectsArray: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            //objectsArray!.count != 0
            var objectIDs = objectsArray!

             NSLog("\(objectIDs)")

            for i in 0...objectIDs.count-1 {
                    self.iDArray.append(objectIDs[i].valueForKey("objectId") as! String)
                    self.NameArray.append(objectIDs[i].valueForKey("SongName") as! String)

                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }

        }
    }

    func grabSong () {
        var songQuery = PFQuery(className: "Songs")
        songQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(iDArray[SelectedSongNumber], block: {
            (object: PFObject?, error : NSError?) -> Void in

            if let AudioFileURLTemporary = object?.objectForKey("SongFile") {
                AudioPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: AudioFileURLTemporary as! NSURL)
                AudioPlayer.play()
            }

        })
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return iDArray.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")
        cell?.textLabel!.text = NameArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell!
    }



    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

       SelectedSongNumber = indexPath.row
        grabSong()

    }




    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

The line that is giving me trouble is `AudioPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: AudioFileURLTemporary as! NSURL)`. Originally the tutorial had this line written as `AudioPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: AudioFileURLTemporary!))` but that doesn't work either.

How do I fix that?

Comment: Just a note, the Xcode tag is for questions that concern the Xcode IDE only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PFFiles aren't in the same class hierarchy as NSURL, so they can't be cast to NSURL. Instead, you need to get get the url string from the url property of the PFFile:

```
func grabSong () {
    var songQuery = PFQuery(className: "Songs")
    songQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(iDArray[SelectedSongNumber], block: {
        (object: PFObject?, error : NSError?) -> Void in

        if let audioFile = object?["SongFile"] as? PFFile {
            let audioFileUrlString: String = audioFile.url  //This might be actually be a String?, I don't remember.
            let audioFileUrl = NSURL(string: audioFileUrlString)!
            AudioPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: audioFileUrl)
            AudioPlayer.play()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It looked like this was the answer but when i tried that i get "ambiguous reference to member url" on the line that is       // let audioFileUrlString: String = audioFile.url ...  (ambiguous ref...)

Comment: Ah sorry. I forgot to typecast the "SongFile" data. I'll update my answer. Hopefully it does the trick.

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to attempt the same thing. I took the code from this link and when I tap the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` it makes a query, but no music plays. @ConfusedByCode

Answer (score 0):

I used this version.

```
item[index].parseFile.getFilePathInBackground { (urlStr, error) in
if (error == nil){

    self.SPB.startAnimation()

    guard let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlStr!) as URL? else {
        return
    }
    self.player = AVPlayer(url: url)

    let videoLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
    videoLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    videoLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
    self.videoView.layer.addSublayer(videoLayer)

    let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
    let duration = asset.duration
    let durationTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration) + 5

    self.SPB.duration = durationTime
    self.player.play()

}
```